# cocoa touch - animating with timers

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am trying to create a simple translation animation to an UIImageView.
At first I was willing to use the [UIView animation] class, but I realized it doesn't give me enough control on the events during the animation(for example, simple collisions with other objects).

I then thought about using a simple thread that would modify the center coordinates of my UIImageView, then sleep and repeat until the animation is complete or until something happens(see:collisions or the object itself disappearing)

This is the code I wrote:

```
-(void)animateImageView:(UIImageView*)view{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    float totalTime=6.0f;
    float elapsedTime=0;
        while(totalTime<=elapsedTime){
                        if(conditions){...}//here are my checks
            CGPoint newCenter=CGPointMake(view.center.x+10, view.center.y);
            view.center=newCenter;
            NSLog(@"%f",view.center.x);
            elapsedTime+=0.1;
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
            }
    [view performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

    [pool release];
```

}

Fact is, my image won't move, but the NSLog command displays the right coordinates where the image's center is.
Ani idea why?
Maybe this is the wrong approach?

Comment: Have you tried to put a [view setNeedsDisplay]; in there? Usually the view gets anyway redrawn if you change the frame but this might be worth a try.

Comment: I tried to insert that line, nothing changes. Sometimes seems like my image moves a tiny bit, I can't understand what i got wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All UIKit classes are not thread-safe. So work with them from main thread only (`view.center=newCenter;`).

Comment: You are right. I made the assignment of the new center via a main thread then called it via performSelectorOnMainThread. It now works. Thank you very much, it would have took me ages to find that out.